# Server upgrade (yum update) removed psql local installation

Tags: centos, yum, amazon-ec2, postgresql

I have installed locally a PostgreSQL server 9.6.2 on aws Centos server a while ago using these commands:

```
rpm -i https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch.rpm 
yum install postgresql96-server -y
```

A few days ago, I have upgraded the server using yum update. Once this process was done I noticed my application stopped working. 
I have found out that the upgrade process manged to somehow conflict with the existing psql installation and to delete the current psql server. (luckily, it was only a dev server...)

My question is: why did it happened? Is it a bug or just me stupidly installing it manually and not excluding it from the yum update command ? Can anybody shed some light on that issue?

These are the details I've collected:

uname -a output:

```
Linux 4.9.85-37.55.amzn1.x86_64
```

yum log

```
Mar 11 13:49:17 Updated: postgresql96-libs-9.6.6-1.79.amzn1.x86_64 
Mar 11 13:49:20 Updated: postgresql96-9.6.6-1.79.amzn1.x86_64 
Mar 11 13:49:26 Updated: postgresql96-server-9.6.6-1.79.amzn1.x86_64

error in yum history info 97 warning: %postun(postgresql96-server-9.6.5-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1


Updated     postgresql96-9.6.5-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 @pgdg96
Update                   9.6.6-1.79.amzn1.x86_64 @amzn-updates
Updated     postgresql96-libs-9.6.5-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 @pgdg96
Update                        9.6.6-1.79.amzn1.x86_64  @amzn-updates
Updated     postgresql96-server-9.6.5-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 @pgdg96
Update                          9.6.6-1.79.amzn1.x86_64  @amzn-updates
```

alternatives:

```
[user@ip alternatives]# alternatives --config psql

There is 1 program that provides 'psql'.
Selection Command

*+ 1 /usr/bin/psql96
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you ended up replacing the version of postgres from the `pgdg96` repo with the one from `amzn-updates` repo. Both packages are called `postgresql96`, so yum/RPM figured one was a direct replacement for the other.

On top of that, while the old package likely also used `alternatives` for selecting the default `psql` binary, I suspect the name of the group was different. Perhaps something such as `pgsql-psql`, where as your new package uses the group `psql`. So on upgrade your system saw this as a new group that you needed to configure, and not an upgrade on an existing group. And it would also seem the `amzn-updates` package doesn't set a default, and requires you to explicitly run `alternatives` to set it.

This is very likely to happen again unless you blacklist the package from one of the 2 repos. Just add `exclude=postgresql96*` to the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` file of the repo you want to disable it on.

Comment: I end up using `yum update --exclude=postgres*` ,
But I will add your suggestion as well.
Many thanks @Patrick!

Comment: Update (Since I can't edit my own comment):
After checking, I found out that 'alternatives' was added by amazon own installation (not by the local psql repo)

Comment: `alternataives` is a standard RHEL utility, which Amazon Linux is based off.

Comment: Off course (-:,    I mentioned it just to point out that `alternatives` had content in it when installing via amazon own installation and not via local installation